# Split a string at every occurrence of arithmetic operator

Tags: javascript, string, split

I have the following variables

```
var arithmetic = "96-66.33+99.3/22*58.2";
var arr;
var operator = "/*+-^";
```

I want to **split** the `arithmetic` at every **occurrence** or `index` of `operator` variable.

The final result will be `["96", "-66.33", "+99.3", "/22", "*58.2"];`

**Final solution provided by V.Roudge**

```js
var arithmetic = "96-66.33+99.3/22*58.2";
arithmetic = arithmetic.split(/(?=[-+*\/])/);
console.log(arithmetic);
```

Comment: Seems like a trivial parser would be what you'd want. But if you're actually building something to do math, and not Smalltalk-style math, you may want an *actual* parser (still pretty trivial) so the order of operations is correct.

Comment: Why would the final result not split out `-66.33` from `96-66.33`?

Comment: The `arithmetic` variable is an input from user, I want to grab the first expression, then continue adding up other items in the array **if available**.

The `arithmetic` variable might be only expression in the array, so splitting wouldn't be necessary.

Comment: @DaveNewton, @Mike McCaughan, If I can achieve this `["96", "-66.33", "+99.3", "/22", "*58.2"];` I'll be appreciate. Seems what I want is complex.

Comment: See my answer. ;)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Closest I could get you through regexp. Very close but not it exactly yet.

```
var arithmetic = "96-66.33+99.3/22*58.2";
arithmetic = arithmetic.split(/([-+*\/])/g);
console.log(arithmetic);
```

EDIT: Got it.

```
var arithmetic = "96-66.33+99.3/22*58.2";
arithmetic = arithmetic.split(/(?=[-+*\/])/);
console.log(arithmetic);
```

```js
var arithmetic = "96-66.33+99.3/22*58.2";
arithmetic = arithmetic.split(/(?=[-+*\/])/);
console.log(arithmetic);
```

Comment: This doesn't return what the OP is asking for.

Comment: Not sure I got it right. What return does he expect ?

Comment: The return he asked for in the question?

Comment: Nice solution bro

Comment: @Abk  remove `-` from regex will get your required result

Answer (score 1):

Wrote a simple parser for it.. But I think regex way is better.

```js
var arithmetic = "96-66.33+99.3/22*58.2";
var operator = {
    "+": true,
    "-": true, 
    "*": true, 
    "/": true 
};
var tokenList = [];
var token = "";
var op = "";
for (var i = 0; i < arithmetic.length; ++i) {
    if (operator[arithmetic[i]]) {
        tokenList.push(op + token);
        token = "";
        op = arithmetic[i];
    } else {
        token += arithmetic[i];
    }
}
tokenList.push(op + token);
console.log(tokenList);
```

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arithmetic = "96-66.33+99.3/22*58.2";
var arr;
var operator = "/*+-^";

for(var i = 0; i < operator.length; i++){
  if(i==0)
    {
  arr = arithmetic.split(operator[i]);
      }
  else 
    {
     arr = arr.toString().split(operator[i]);
    }
  
  
}
console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You don't understand my question. Please refer to the question again

Comment: @Abk oh then you have to do parsing

Answer (score 0):

```js
var arithmetic = "96-66.33+99.3/22*58.2";
var arr=[];
var operator = "/*+-^";

var re = /[+-\/\*]/;
   
  arr = arithmetic.split(re);
  

console.log(arr);
```

Comment: You don't understand my question. Please refer to the question again.

Comment: The final result will be `["96-66.33", "+99.3", "/22", "*58.2"];`

Comment: what the logic man! without logic how we can process the string ?

Comment: If I can achieve this `["96", "-66.33", "+99.3", "/22", "*58.2"];` I'll be appreciate. Seems what I want is complex